# How to restrict decimal value for two digits and restrict decimal more than one in numeric value

Tags: javascript

I have one amount field in that i want to restrict user after decimal they can not use more than two values:

1. After decimal there should be only two values that are option.
2. User can not type more than one decimal in the field.

I am using following regix for that its not working can any one help.

```
function validate(evt) {

    if (evt.keyCode == 8) { return true; }// for backspace problem in mozilla

    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /[0-9 ]|\,\d{1,2}/;

    if (!regex.test(key)) 
    {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's much better UX to simply let the user enter what he wants but then tell him it's invalid.

Comment: What about numbers like `002.45`?

Comment: That i am showing as a message after submitting . but i want to restrict the user .

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be accomplished using HTML only by setting the STEP and MAX of your numeric field such as

```html
<form>
 <input type="number" name="myNumber" required=true step=".01">
 <button>send</button>
</form>
```

please let me know if this is what your looking for but this will mean that any value entered must be numeric(thus only 1 decimal point) it must be less than or equal to 1 (you can set to .99 if you dont want to include 1) and it must be an increment of .01(so it can only have 2 decimal places.

Just re-read your question you can remove the max(i thought i read no more than 1.0)

Comment: That will still allow the user to override the value and physically type something like `1.456677`.

Comment: edited in the REQUIRED attribute. most current browsers will ensure these conditions are meet. but i understand where your comming from as older browsers wont validate and neither will safari i do believe

Comment: Adding `required` doesn't solve the problem. I can still enter a value of `1.98888888888` and Chrome will allow me to blur the field without any validation errors (because the value is a valid value)...

Comment: Alright. Did i missunderstand the question or is it simply not doing what i said it would do?

Comment: @BenM I am using chrome right now and when you click submit or enter key it gives a error saying to enter a valid value

Comment: There is any way to control this using regix

Comment: I want every thing on keypress it should not allow at all

Comment: Then the simplest way to do this would probably be to use if statements. Can you please first state what is a valid option and what isnt and ill give you javascript to validate the entry upon keystroke

Comment: @kapilsharma my interpritation of what you stated above in the requirements are either you are looking for no more than 2 more decimal places or only 2 acceptable values after the decimal place such as 1.1 and 1.2 are valid but 1.3 and 1.4 are not. please clarify

Comment: i am looking for two more value after decimal not more than two digit it can be from 00 to 99

Answer (score 0):

```js
var previousValue;

function numberChanged(element){
  if(validateMe(element)==false){
      element.value=previousValue;
    }else{
      previousValue=element.value;
  
  }

function validateMe(element){
     wholeNumber=element.value.split(".")[0];
    if(element.value.split(".").length==1){
      if(wholeNumber<-1 || > 999999999){
              
          return false;
          }
    }else if(element.value.split(".").length==2){
        decimalValue=element.value.split(".")[1];
        if(decimalValue>-1 && decimalValue<100){
                if(wholeNumber<-1 || > 999999999){
              
          return false;
          }
          }else{
            return false;
            }
    }else{
        return false;
     }
  
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myNumber" onChange="numberChanged(this)" />
```

Comment: This line seems incorrect: `if(element.value.split(".").length=1){`.